# Como saber o tamanho elemento do elemento pai e mudar atributos dos elementos filhos? [styled components]

Tags: css, react, styled-components

Boa tarde, como faço pra saber o tamanho de um elemento pra conseguir mudar o `width` de outro elemento filho?

Eu tenho um elemento Container que embrulha a `Table`
quando a `table` tiver um `width` maior que `1400px` eu quero conseguir saber e manipular o pai `Container` para mudar alguns valores dele, por exemplo:
eu não quero mais que o `thead th` seja:

```
  thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
```

e sim seja:

```
thead th {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

elemento Container:

```
const Container
 = styled.div`
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  width: 1368px;

  thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

`
```

componente container e table:

```
<Container>
   <Table>
    {renders}
   </Tabled>
</Container>
```

Comment: @media (min-width: 1400px) { Container > table thead th {position:static;} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter que usar o [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) para "pegar" o elemento e o [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) para pegar o width toda vez que ele mudar.

Ai é só verificar e alterar o style.

Algo assim:

```
const ref = useRef(null);
const [style, setStyle] = useState({
  position: sticky,
  top: 0
});
useEffect(() => {
  const width = ref.current ? ref.current.offsetWidth : 0;

  if (width > 1400) {
    setStyle({
      position: relative,
      top: `10px`,
    })
  }

}, [ref.current]);


<Container>
  <table ref={ref}>
    <thead>
      <th style={{...style}}>

      </th>
    </thead>
  </table>

</Container>
```